# jQuery - how to create smooth effect for this slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a slider, what have an active item which is larger than others. When the controls are clicked, the next/prev item gets the active class. It is working, but I'd like to add a smooth effect for this. Any ideas?

Code:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#wrap').find('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    $('#wrap img:first').remove().appendTo('#wrap');
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    $('#wrap').find('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    $('#wrap img:last').remove().prependTo('#wrap');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zXjzU/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you define as a "smooth" effect, but a really simple solution given your existing code would be to just add a `transition:width 1s` to your `#wrap img` CSS. [See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXjzU/2/):

```
#wrap img {
    width: 100px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 5px 30px 5px;
    transition:width 1s;
}
```

I'm not sure that **I'd** construct a carousel like this, I'd probably use `position`s so that my elements scrolled into the center of screen, but it's pretty easy to Google a solution for that too if that's what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I meant exactly what you've said, when controls are clicked, the next/prev item scrolls smoothly in center.

Comment: I think that's for usual sliders (when only one image is shown), not for this case

Comment: And you can't find a slider anywhere on Google?

Comment: Show me one with the same effect.